Not Working : Get jobTitle and other contact details from user and enter into SharePoint list field with JSON formatting
I m trying to reference to other contact details (except from email and title) but I don't get the value.
For example : [$InternalNameofField.jobTitle]

Two points need to be noted:

the corresponding employee JobTitle needs to have a value
the view needs to show the corresponding people field

Test Result:

